# Windows 10 menus all screwed up

Tags: windows-10

I have Windows 10, and just recently the menus on programs and some text in text boxes are all stretched and weird. It's quite hard to describe, so here's a picture from Notepad:

[image]

Another example from my display settings:

[image]

What's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a driver issue. I updated my graphics driver through AMD Radeon Settings and it fixed the text stretching.